# Where can I ask questions about charging for open-source projects?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm thinking of asking a question along the lines of:

> Why does Mono for Android cost money if the mono project is opensource and therefore everything based on it must be opensource?

Where would be the best site to post this? I found it inappropriate for the main Stack Overflow.

See [Why does Mono for Android cost money if the mono project is opensource and therefore everything based on it must be opensource?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220676/why-does-mono-for-android-cost-money-if-the-mono-project-is-opensource-and-there)

Comment: Afaik, it is offtopic everywhere on SE. For your question: You can sell linux, noone cares, the GPL allows that.

Comment: There is a proposal at Area 51: [Open Source Licensing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58715/open-source-licensing)

Comment: `and therefore everything based on it must be opensource?` That doesn't sound right. Where do you take this information from?

Comment: Related: [Monodroid Free Alternative? (.NET on Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7750107)

Comment: Just fyi just because something is open source doesn't mean everything based on it must be. For example commercial products are made using jmonkey engine;  an open source graphics library

Answer (score 5):

Questions about software licensing are on topic on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). You'll find more details on what questions the site welcomes in its [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help), and related questions under its [licensing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) and [open-source](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) tags.

That said, there are a couple of misconceptions in your question:

- open source != [free as in beer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre).
- not every open source license requires derivative works to also be open source.

Please take some time to research your question (and open source licensing in general) before you post it. If you ask it as is you'll most probably end up with a negative net score, and perhaps a close vote or two.